# Control synchro system

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, synchronous

[image]

I have some questions regarding this system that is supposed to take in an input signal and move the load according to this signal. The current load position is feedback to the CT, which compares the current position to the desired position and produces an error signal that is amplified by the amplifier. I understand the processes involving the CT being connected with the CX and comparing it to produce an error signal but am unsure about other things. CX is a control transmitter and CT is a control transformer

1.What type of feedback inductive position sensor component is used and how does it work? Or is the CT THE feedback component

2. How exactly does the amplifier amplify the error signal that makes the load move to the correct position. Quite unclear about this

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: "current" may be an unfortunate word choice ... current feedback is used for torque control and I think you are discussing position control.

Comment: ??? Current as in the existing position...

Comment: The CT is the feedback component : its rotor is connected to the motor (actuator) shaft to provide feedback. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchro. Second question seems to reduce to ... how does an amplifier amplify?

Comment: Why is the CT connected to the motor? How is it supposed to compare the load position to the desired position?

Comment: The connection to the motor (more accurately, to the actuator shaft controlling load position) is how the CT sees position. The desired position is encoded by the CX into 3 phase into the CT : the amplitutes of those phases corresponds to the desired position. The CT output is the sine of the difference between desired position and load position, which will be 0 when load is in the right position.

Comment: What are Linear Variable differential transformers or inductive position transducer sensing devices? Apparently those are used as feedback

Comment: Wiki has all the generic answers

Comment: Please reserve the word current for electrical current. Use "present", "momentary" or similar instead.

Comment: I don't think its that hard to understand that when I say curent position, I'm not referring an electrical current